# Open another app by deeplink and get result on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new on Swift. Thats why my question may be incorrect.

So, I have two apps.

On first app I click login button that opens second app by deeplink. This works fine, but I don't know how to return result from second app.

First app:

```
// FIRST APP
// After click action
let url = URL(string: "lg://loginapp.com/login"){
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
    }else{
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```

I don't know how to wait for result and how to return it from second app.

On second app I need to login user and return to first app token or something like this.

Now code on my second app is just like this. But must close with returning rusult.

```
// SECOND APP
let result = args["result"] as? String{
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *){
        UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend))
    }else{
        UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(NSXPCConnection.suspend))
    }
}
```

Please give me some directions.

Comment: The second app will need to use a deeplink to open the first app and pass the data

Comment: And what if the second app is app like facebook auth. I mean multiple apps opens second app. How will be the second app detect which app called him?

Comment: Apps that provide authentication services typically accept a response URL that they will invoke.  Normally OAuth or SAML is used.  For Facebook you wouldn't typically call the Facebook app directly. You would invoke the Facebook OAuth endpoint, providing the return URL for your app.  The Facebook OAuth service will then determine how to authenticate the user. This may involve opening the Facebook app.  At the end of the authentication process the token will be returned to the URL you supplied (which could be your app's deep link)

Comment: Also, if you are using an OAuth type flow you should use `ASWebAuthenticationViewController` rather than simply opening the URL. This potentially allows the authentication to proceed in your app

Comment: Add additional parameters to your URL (First App → Second App).
"lg://loginapp.com/login?origin=lol://anotherApp.com/return/originDeeplinkUrl"

Second App can do anything and take the origin value to call the deeplink from origin App.